# Search bar using Window. Find in js and html

Tags: javascript, html, search

Hello I am trying to make a search bar to search anything which is available on a html page. I used `window.find` method.it highlights the string if its available in the html page. It returns a boolean value true or false. It gives false if the searched string is not available. But main problem is that it also returns false if all the searched strings are highlighted.Then how can I message the user that Nothing found OR searched text is already highlighted.
I also want to Search again if button clicked again also when all the searched text is highlighted .

I AM USING THIS CODE BUT ITS NOT COMPLETING MY ALL WISHES THAT I WANT.

JS

```
function  SEARCH(){
 var Search=document.getElementById("Search").value;
 var result=window.find(Search);
 if (result == false) {
  alert("Nothing found or already highlighted "
); }
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="FLDS" type="text" id="Search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button onclick="SEARCH()" id="SEARCHIT">SEARCH</button>

<p>    A paragraph is a self-contained unit of discourse in writing dealing with a particular point or idea. A paragraph consists of one or more sentences. Though not required by the syntax of any language, paragraphs are usually an expected part of formal writing, used to organize longer prose.   </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend maybe trying to implement some PHP Ajax into your code and look at this link https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp. If you're confused about how to do it reach out to me zackhitane@gmail.com and I can help you through it.

Comment: Thanks for giving time.  I have never used php can you give a example with some codes.

Comment: The livesearch example search in a db of links which is server-side while the question seems to focus on search in the html loaded client side. Can you explain here how the livesearch example could be used to achieve that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).